# jqgrid is unclickable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

my jqgrid is unclickable because it is under a dialog box that says: WARNING PLease, select row... (see picture)[image]

although the dialog box is at the bottom of the page, it seems the jqgrid is under the layer of the dialog box... when i try to click the X button of the dialog box, it doesnt close.

here is my implementation of jqrid:

```
 $('#grid2').jqGrid({
    url: '/Room/JsonRoom',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['ROOM NAME', 'OPERATIONS'],
    colModel: [
{ name: 'ROOM NAME', index: 'name', width: 200, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'OPERATIONS', index: 'operation', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center'}],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'name',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    width: 900,
    height: "100%",
    caption: "ROOMS"
});
jQuery("#grid2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { width: 600 });
```

how could i fix this...

UPDATE: 
here's the way i call css and js files

```
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you forgot to include jQuery UI CSS. In any way you should verify the *full* HTML code on the page including all CSS, JavaScript files and there order.

Comment: @eaon21: You should verify which files and in *which order* will be included. For example you should first include `jQuery.js`, then `grid.locale-en.js` and only then `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Moreover you should verify whether `ResolveBundleUrl` really work. For example look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9624155/315935).

Answer (score 0):

I know this, I was also faced this long back.
This is mainly due to `model` and `jqModel`.

```
modal:true,  
jqModal:true,
```

if you have like above in your grid code, you can't click a background objects when ever a dialog or alert message is there as popup.

Put code like this in your grid code: `modal:false, jqModal:true, <your remaining code>`.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217920/jqgrid-edit-form-closing-when-click-off-form/8224212#8224212).

Comment: no errors... is modal and jqmodal attribs supported by jqgrid?

Comment: Yes, see `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` source file.

Comment: Your problem is with modal, and jqModal only... use right combination with true and false.